# How to create dashboard combining maps and charts open source way?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, chart, d3, dashboard

As far as I am aware there is no open source user interface (framework) which would allow easily design website as combination of interactive maps and charts like ArcGIS dashboard tool does. And you can't go without at least basic coding skills and combination of tools. **What is currently the closest it gets to create interactive web GIS dashboard in open source world?**

**In particular, what would it take to create open source alternative dashboard to [coronavirus dashboard](https://gisanddata.maps.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6)?** We talk client side only solution, which must be capable to connect to GIS servers (consume GIS services).

My understanding is currently you must have some coding skills, and use some combination of following tools:

1. [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) - main framework to design page / grid
2. [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) or [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org/) to incorporate interactive maps
3. [D3.js](https://d3js.org/) or [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) to incorporate interactive charts

By initial search combination of Bootstrap, Leaflet and D3.js seems to be the most used way these days to incorporate interactive maps and charts into dashboard like website. Is that correct?

Comment: This [website](http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2016/08/interactive-data-visualization-geospatial-d3-dc-leaflet-python/) gives you an insight of what is necessary to create an interactive dashboard based on open source platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it still works for you, there's [Mapstore](https://mapstore2.readthedocs.io/en/user_docs/) option. You can set up a dashboard in open source environment without code. Of course, there's a developer way if you want.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was waiting for, excellent that someone finally put it together, thank you.